# Python - Separate last sentence from string in a list

Tags: python, string

I have a string like

```
x = 'Test. Test1. Test test test.'
```

Now I would like to separate the last sentence (meaning the last set of strings that start with a capital letter) from the rest of the strings in a list. How's that possible?

Comment: Please add more examples of expected input, this may not as simple as you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `[A-Z][^A-Z]*$` to fetch that.
Example:

```py
import re
s='Test. Test1. Test test test.'
last_sentence=re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*$',s)
print(last_sentence)
```

Output:

```py
['Test test test.']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You can use `re.split` base `capital chars` and return two last elements of result.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'Test. Test1. Test test test.'

>>> re.split(r'([A-Z])', x)
['', 'T', 'est. ', 'T', 'est1. ', 'T', 'est test test.']
# you want this : ----------------^^^ and ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

>>> re.split(r'([A-Z])', x)[-2:]
['T', 'est test test.']

>>> ''.join(re.split(r'([A-Z])', x)[-2:])
'Test test test.'
```

Explanation:

- `[A-Z]` : which allows any upper case letter between : (A-Z) -> A,B, ..., X, Y, Z

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'Test. Test1. Test test test.'

separated = x[13:]

print(separated)
```

You can use an index from where you want the sentence to start, leaving no value after the colon means "until the end". If you need more conditions such as "from a capital letter", then the other answer may be more suited